# node js twit cannot recive protect account's mention

Tags: node.js, twitter

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
  });


var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {track : 'keyword'});
stream.on('message', function (tweet) {
    console.log(tweet.text)
  })
```

I use this code, but this cannot work when protect account user mention. (Im Following yes) How can I do It?

Answer (score 0):

Fill in those valid values.

```
{
    consumer_key:         '...'
  , consumer_secret:      '...'
  , access_token:         '...'
  , access_token_secret:  '...'
}
```

- consumer_key with your OAuth Consumer Key
- consumer_secret with your OAuth Consumer Secret
- access_token with your OAuth Access Token
- token_secret with your OAuth Access Token Secret

ref : [developer.twitter/quick-start](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/hide-replies/quick-start)

Comment: I did it, but notting fixed.